# Select Last N days data based on datetime column

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have datetime column and its values are like below

```
2021-04-13 15:31:59
2021-04-13 15:29:59
2021-04-12 15:31:59
2021-04-12 15:29:59
2021-04-10 15:31:59
2021-04-10 15:29:59
2021-04-8 15:31:59
2021-04-8 15:29:59
```

I want to select the last 3 days data available in table

In above example it is 2021-04-10 , 2021-04-12 and 2021-04-13

I tried something like below

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE DATE(`timer`) >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 3 DAY
```

But its returning data from 2021-04-12 , since there is no data available from 2021-04-11.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: Server version: 10.2.32-MariaDB  and  mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MariaDB 10.2.32 you can use `DENSE_RANK()` window function:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY DATE(timer) DESC) rnk
  FROM tablename
) t
WHERE rnk <= 3
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=5dd21cd54e216ab4303e4c3a4c5bf44d).

Comment: Thank you I get the warning -  Current selection does not contain a unique column and also speed of query has reduced from 0.003 to 0.03..

Comment: @Graciewilliams The warning (is it phpMyAdmin?) is about your data and not about the query. About the speed, why do you say it reduced? Compared to what?

Comment: yes phpmyadmin , I don't get that error for normal SELECT * FROM `price` ORDER BY `timer` DESC and regarding time If u see the query in my question it took 0.003 seconds only. but this is taking 0.03 seconds.. Is that ok ?

Comment: @Graciewilliams The query in your question scans the table once and filters out the rows that do not satisfy the condition. But is not the solution to your problem because it ignores non existing dates. This is why I use a window function. My query scans the table once to assign rank number to the rows, based on the dates and then again scans  the results to filter out rows.

Comment: ok thank you , is there a way just to sort last 3 days ? and run query greater than the last day ? ,, I think its possible to get unqiue column in DATE column,, but is there a way in DATETIME  ?

Comment: @Graciewilliams to sort the results use: `ORDER BY timer DESC` at the end of the query. For *run query greater than the last day ?* I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I have some table with very large number of columns , this query is too slow, is there any alternative way to achieve this ?

Comment: @Graciewilliams your requirement is not simple. Don't compare this query to your query because they don't solve the same problem. You must rank the dates in the table before filtering. Also, window functions, when applicable, are usually the best choice.